# How to pass '<ClassName>.class' as an argument in java?

Tags: java, jaxb

I am trying to make a generalized method which would convert a POJO object to a XML string.

And I am trying to use this method to achieve this goal.

```
public class Util{

    public static String jaxbObjectToXML(Object xmlObj) {
        String xmlString = "";
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(POJO.class);
            Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
            marshaller.marshal(xmlObj, stringWriter);
            xmlString = stringWriter.toString();
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return xmlString;
    }
}
```

Now in line `JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(**POJO.class**);` , I am trying to get this POJO value to be generic.
Like if I could pass the class name, object or something which could do the work. Also adding the appropriate parameter to the method.

Comment: Try passing Class object as argument like Class cls.
Then JAXBContext.newInstance(cls);

Comment: Tried that but it did not worked :(

Answer (score 0):

You could just use following:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Util {
    @XmlElement
    private String name;
    @XmlElement
    private String description;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Util xmlObj = new Util();
        xmlObj.name = "Alex";
        xmlObj.description = "Alex Rose";
        jaxbObjectToXML(xmlObj, xmlObj.getClass());
    }

    public static <T> String jaxbObjectToXML(T xmlObj, Class<? extends T> aClass) { {
        String xmlString = "";
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(aClass);
            Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
            marshaller.marshal(xmlObj, System.out);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return xmlString;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<util>
    <name>Alex</name>
    <description>Alex Rose</description>
</util>
```

Or `JAXBContext.newInstance(xmlObj.getClass());`

Comment: Changed to generic version